# I want to set Seekbar to zero when remove touch

Tags: android

i m using seekbar in a game in which i want it to set to zero location by default when user leave it

```
   verticalSeekBar=(VerticalSeekBar)findViewById(R.id.vertical_Seekbar);

    vsProgress=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.vertical_sb_progresstext);
   tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);

    verticalSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {


        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            setProgress(0);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            vsProgress.setText(progress+"");
            if(progress==10)
            {
                check();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
 VerticalSeekBar.setProgress(0);
```

instead of

```
  seekBar.setProgress(0);
```

Comment: Sorry, Instead of simply setProgress(0); use the first one